# sqldf "NOT IN" function

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm having troubles trying to show the result of my sqldf query:

```
NonMovedProductRecordsT <- sqldf("
        SELECT a.ID, a.Supplier, a.Code, a.Name as Description, a.NDFProd as [From NDFProd], a.NDFPack as [From NDFPack], a.QtyFct as [From QtyFct], 
        b.Description as [From Description], a.NDFProd as [To NDFProd], a.NDFPack as [To NDFPack], a.QtyFct as [To QtyFct], b.Description as [To Description], 
        'Not Moved' as [Total Edit Units], 'NotMoved' AS [Edit Value], 'Not_Moved' AS APIdifference, '' AS Checked, a.Active
        FROM (select distinct Supplier, Code from ProductCodingChangesT) as p
        INNER JOIN (ProductT as a
        INNER JOIN (NDFLKUPT as b
        INNER JOIN NDFLKUPTKeyT as c ON b.NDF = c.NDF) ON (a.NDFPack = c.pack_cd) AND (a.NDFProd = c.prod_cd)) ON (p.Code = a.Code) AND (p.Supplier = a.Supplier)
        WHERE a.ID NOT IN (select ID from ProductCodingChangesT) and a.Superceded > ',HistoryStart,';")
```

I tried messing with it in both SQL Server and R and it appears that the line:
`a.ID NOT IN (select ID from ProductCodingChangesT)`
is where the problem seems to be when I tried dissecting it.

I checked all dataframes to see if they are correct and they seem to be fine.
I was wondering if `NOT IN` function works in SQLite. I couldn't find any alternative for this nor any resources similar to my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sqlite supoports NOT IN.  See the 4th from the bottom non-indented line of the syntax diagram at the top of this page: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: my syntax seems to be correct. I am not sure why it won't capture the correct output when I run it. i checked both columns and they are both in numeric format so they should be capturing it.

Comment: I did try this and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Add the verbose=TRUE argument to sqldf and see if the your paste is giving you what you think.  Also, you really need to follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and provide your question in reproducible form so others can run the code since there isn't really enough information in the question to really answer it definitively.